# Ruby1.9 and Amazon SQS?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-1.9, amazon-sqs

Is there a good library/gem for accessing Amazon SQS from ruby1.9? The Amazon ruby example and right_aws do not work as-is with ruby1.9.

I'd strongly prefer something that's known to work under reasonably heavy load (a few hundred thousand queue items or more per day).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official right_aws gem (>=2.0) seems to work with Ruby 1.9.2

http://rubygems.org/gems/right_aws

UPDATE:
Amazon recently made an official gem which has SQS support: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/

Comment: Appoxy AWS has also been updated and works with recent versions of ruby.

Answer (score 6):

Try the Appoxy AWS library, it was forked from right_aws a while back just for Ruby 1.9 and has come along way since then supporting a lot more than right_aws now.

http://github.com/appoxy/aws/

Answer (score 1):

The comments on [isitruby19.com](http://isitruby19.com/right_aws) point to a patch and a fork of the right_aws gem which provide Ruby 1.9 support.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Sqskiq](https://github.com/ricardolazaro/sqskiq) page for details of how to process messages in background in a easy way. This gem uses celluloid actors (like sidekiq does) and has features to avoid/minimizes sqs costs.

Answer (score 0):

This [FanSQS](https://github.com/vkhang55/FanSQS) gem supports SQS. I haven't test it with Ruby 1.9 but looks very promising.